# Languages drop down menu in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I would like to create a drop-down menu for language selection. It is an MVC database application. I would like the user to be able to choose multiple languages.

What I want to know is how to connect my model to the razor view. And what kind of attributes I can use above the property of the class?

This is a snapshot of the model class I have:

```
public class CrewViewModel
    {
 // This is the date of birth property
        [Required]
        [DisplayName("Date of Birth")]
        [DataType(DataType.Date)]
        [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-dd-mm}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
        public DateTime DOB { get;  
 // Here goes the code for the Languages property
    }
```

And what razor code to use in the view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are lots of ways to do it, I have done this in the past by creating a specific class to wire up my values:

```
public class LanguageItem
{
    public bool Disabled { get; set; }
    public string Value { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Then you can create your property in your model as:

```
public IEnumerable<LanguageItem> Languages
{
    get
    {
         return new List<LanguageItem>
          {
              new LanguageItem {Name = "English", Value = "en-US"}
          };
    }
}
```

or however you populate yours. Create a field for the selection (i.e. SelectedLanguage). Then something like...

```
 @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedLanguage, new SelectList(Model.Languages, "Value", "Text"), "Language")
```

Should work

Comment: I keep getting a System.NullReferenceException